# Just starting to code and having a hard time with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-helper

How do I pull input from the text boxes to display them back on the screen once the user clicks the submit button. My JS is a mess and really makes no sense. If somebody could help me get the ball rolling I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can't eat an elephant all in one bite...keep plugging away at learning. If you want help here though you need to post code specific problems. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Also, personally, it is slightly confusing that you're referencing javascript(JS) in your title and body, yet you have `jquery` as a tag.  Jquery is a javascript library and both it and vanilla javascript can do what your asking..... but which are you after?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/ here learn from the site.. it really is a good starting point since you said you are "Just starting to code"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to copy values from an input to another html tag:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="waffles" />
<button type="button" onclick="$('#copiedValue').html($('#myInput').val())">Copy value</button>
<span id="copiedValue"></span>
```

The jQuery is all in `onclick` which pulls the value from the input using `$('#myInput').val()` and supplies that value as an argument to replace the html contents of the span `$('#copiedValue').html(...)`.

Here is a jsfiddle with the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/njacwybg/